# Spring Data JPA method for deleting using a two fields in the embaddable key

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

THis is the main entity class, which is having an embeddedId

```
public class LabResHivMutation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private LabResHivMutationPK id;

    private String comments;

    @Column(name="MUTATION_TYPE_ID")
    private BigDecimal mutationTypeId;

    @Column(name="VALUE")
    private String value;   

}
```

This is the embeddable key

```
@Embeddable
public class LabResHivMutationPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="TO_INST")
    private Long toInst;

    @Column(name="REL_INVSTID")
    private long relInvstid;

    @Column(name="MUTATION_ID")
    private long mutationId;

}
```

Is there any delete methos available in spring data Jpa to delete based on only two of the embaddable key(toInst,relInvstid).

I still can write a JPQL query to delete it. My question is there any method available for this.

like deleteById ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is, `repo.deleteByIdToInstAndIdRelInvstid(toInst,relInnvstid)`
As you see you have to specify deleteBy`Id`ToInst , this is how you reference a field of an embedded ID , the same as you would reference a field of a foreign relation. Here `Id` matches your field naming

```
@EmbeddedId
private LabResHivMutationPK id;
```

Comment: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [om.gov.moh.ais.lab.entity.LabResHivMutation#om.gov.moh.ais.lab.entity.LabResHivMutationPK@7dd46]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [om.gov.moh.ais.lab.entity.LabResHivMutation#om.gov.moh.ais.lab.entity.LabResHivMutationPK@7dd46]

Comment: If there is no records to delete it throws exception. In case of query it doesn't throw any exception even there is no record.

Comment: It's normal to thrown an exception when deleting entities by Id that does not exists. It's an unexpected scenario since you got that Id from a query result and now it's gone. If when deleting, you don't provide the Id's you obtained as a query result, but instead you have another way to input these Id's (user input, other systems input , etc...) then maybe that field should not be part of the primary key, it should be an attribute, which you can index it to be unique if that's the case. As for the exception above, I have never seen it so I can't give you additional help on it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to delete an entity: either using its own "**JPA Repository derived delete method**" `long deleteByFirstIdAndSecondId(long firstId , secondId)` 
In your service you can simply call it : `repository.deleteByFirstIdAndSecondId(long firstId , secondId)`

Another way is through the parent entity by excluding the child entity (or entities depends on the relation type).

Answer (score 0):

User underscore '_' when entity will have multiple keys with using @Embedded keys.
example :repository.deleteByid_toInst();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).